# Что делать если говорят что операнды / и * не поддерживаются в типе данных String, хотя я их перевёл в int? (C#)

Tags: c#, калькулятор

Код:

```cs
using System;

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите действие (+ - * /)");
        string act;
        act = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");
        string a;
        a = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt32(a);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число:");
        string b;
        b = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt32(b);
        if (act == "+") {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {a + b}");
        } else if (act == "-") {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {a - b}");
        } else if (act == "*") {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {a * b}");
        } else if (act == "/") {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {a / b}");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Действие выбрано неверно");
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```cs
main.cs(21,48): error CS0019: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `string' and `string'
main.cs(23,48): error CS0019: Operator `/' cannot be applied to operands of type `string' and `string'
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Я перевёл переменные a и b в Int, (Convert.ToInt32(a), Convert.ToInt32(b)), но не работает, все равно программа думает что я работаю со строкой.
Что делать?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, ещё и я напишу свой ответ.

В C# все переменные и константы не могут менять свой тип данных после их объявления. По этой причине (и, возможно, ещё парочке других) все преобразования и приведения типов сводятся к созданию новой переменной на основе значения "старой" и возврату этой новой переменной.

Метод `Convert.ToInt32(...);` принимает как аргумент строку, создаёт на основе неё число и возвращет его как результат. Переданная строка не превращается в число!

Вы можете сохранить значение, возвращенное методом, в переменную, чтобы использовать его в дальнейшем:

```
string aString = "1";
int aNumber    = Convert.ToInt32(number1String); // строка осталось строкой; aNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

Это функция, её результат должен быть присвоен целочисленной переменной

Answer (score 1):

Есть так же вариант с `parse`:

`int num = int.Parse("5"); // 5`

Однако, что `int.Parse`, что методы класса `Convert` при неудачной конвертации выбрасывают исключение (убивают приложение, `Convert.ToInt32("Hello")`), ловить их можно только через `try..catch`. Для таких случаев есть вариант получше - `int.TryParse`. Первым параметром принимает строку, которую нужно конвертировать, а вторым - переменную (с `out`), где нужно сохранить значение, если все пройдет удачно. А сама она возвращает `true/false` (удалась/не удалась конвертация)

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(input, out int num)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {num * 2}");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите корректное число!");
}
```

Будет полезно читать: [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Ответ: {Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b)}");
```

И подобным образом для остальных операций.

Comment: конкретно в данном примере, я считаю, не лучший вариант, так как гораздо удобнее сохранить результаты операций в `int`-переменные и пользоватся уже ими в `switch`